# Getting wrong month

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [pk_Id]
      ,[fk_resumeID]
      ,[fk_LoginID]
      ,[fk_CompanyId]
      ,Convert(nvarchar(11),ViewDate,105)
  FROM [RecruitingDB].[Recruiting].[tbl_ViewResumeStatus]
   where  Convert(nvarchar(10),ViewDate,106) 
               between Convert(nvarchar(10),'17-10-2015',106) and  Convert(nvarchar(10),'23-10-2015',106)
```

I am using this above sql for getting only Oct. Record but I am getting Sept. record.

Have you any idea why this is happening.

Comment: Don't compare character strings, compare dates!

Comment: @jarlh didi't get can you please explain or any example for the same.

Comment: between 17-10-2015 and 23-10-2015 would return, say 22-09-2015, as they are just character strings and 22 is between 17 and 23

Comment: @colmde I am Compare date not number. If i use and 22 is between 17 and 23 then I get all number between these 2 number

Comment: which datatype AND format in case it is a char(example dd-mm-yyyy) is ViewDate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the alphabetic values. You should avoid that, when dealing with numeric or date values.

Example `17-10-2015` would unintentionally be between `16-01-2015` and `18-01-2015`

Use this instead:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [pk_Id]
      ,[fk_resumeID]
      ,[fk_LoginID]
      ,[fk_CompanyId]
      ,Convert(char(10),ViewDate,105)
  FROM [RecruitingDB].[Recruiting].[tbl_ViewResumeStatus]
  WHERE
    ViewDate > '2015-10-17' and
    ViewDate < dateadd(d, 1, '2015-10-23')
```

If ViewDate is a date, you can replace the *WHERE* clause with this:

```
  WHERE 
    ViewDate BETWEEN '2015-10-17' and '2015-10-23'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it will do if you convert your dates to strings. Your query is looking for anything alphabetically between'17-10-2015' and '23-10-2015'. So for example that would include '18-09-2015'.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do date arithmetic using strings.  If for some reason you *have* to, then use YYYY-MM-DD formats:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [pk_Id], [fk_resumeID], [fk_LoginID], [fk_CompanyId],
       Convert(nvarchar(11),ViewDate,105)
FROM [RecruitingDB].[Recruiting].[tbl_ViewResumeStatus]
WHERE ViewDate >= '2015-10-17' AND ViewDate < '2015-10-24';
```

Also, note the use of the comparisons.  `BETWEEN` can be dangerous, because the column could have a time component.  This method works regardless of whether or not the column has a time component.  And, it will take advantage of an index on `ViewDate`.

The following is also acceptable in SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [pk_Id], [fk_resumeID], [fk_LoginID], [fk_CompanyId],
       Convert(nvarchar(11),ViewDate,105)
FROM [RecruitingDB].[Recruiting].[tbl_ViewResumeStatus]
WHERE CAST(ViewDate as date) BETWEEN '2015-10-17' AND '2015-10-23';
```

The conversion to date remove the time component.  And, the function call is sargable, meaning that the query can still use an index on `ViewDate`.

Comment: getting error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Hmmm, there is one case where the internationalization settings for SQL Server mess up on YYYY-MM-DD format.  The universal format in SQL Server is YYYYMMDD (without the hyphens), so you can try `BETWEEN '20151017' and '20151023'`.  (I prefer the hyphens because they are ISO standard and easier to read.)